# Wait in Javascript loop synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I have a javascript `for loop` iterating through an array of elements and adding a class to them, then remove the class ro change the color of the element for one or two seconds and then revert it to the previous color. I need a synchronous wait in the code between add and remove, which pauses the `for loop` and do nothing to show the color, or else changing class will not be affected.

```
for (var i=1; i<array.length; i++){
    array[i-1].addClass('something');
    array[i].addClass('something');
//WAIT, PAUSE THE LOOP for two seconds
    array[i-1].removeClass('something');
    array[i].removeClass('something');
}
```

Comment: the only way that can be done that simply is definitely not recommended

Comment: Just wrap it in a timeout, and the browser will have time to repaint

Comment: javascript is single threaded. hence this is a bad idea.

Comment: *"I need a synchronous wait in the code between add and remove"* No, you don't, because it would lock up the browser UI. What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: use babel and async / await / yield

Comment: @DanielA.White: *JavaScript* is not single-threaded. *Browsers* run a single main JavaScript thread (and as many worker threads as you like). JavaScript can be, and is, multi-threaded in other environments.

Comment: what T.J. says. in addition to have a bit more clearification: everything your browser renders is running in the same thread as javascript. this means you  really want to avoid any syncronous execution at all. as i said: take a look at babel, async, await and yield. they solve your problem of creating asyncronous code even though the code looks syncronous

Comment: you can also use yield async and await in your browser but you have to take care about browser support for it. babel is simply a transpiler that compiles future spec javascript down to earlier versions of javascript. in some months you can basically get rid of this and use it directly in every major browser